# Efficient Coding

Tags: excel, format, coding-efficiency

Morning

I'm not an experienced coder, however I have written some code in VBA that writes data back to an excel spreadsheet. The code works, but I have two rows of code and was wondering if there is a more efficient method of writing the code the do the same thing. Below is the lines of code I am taking about:

```
xComp.Range("B" & xLine).Value = TB_CompAdded.Value
xComp.Range("B" & xLine).Value = Format(xComp.Range("B" & xLine).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

I'm hoping that there is a method of writing the code as a single line.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `xComp.Range("B" & xLine).Value = Format(TB_CompAdded.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")`?

Comment: Not sure what is happening now, but when I change the line to as shown above the values are coming from the spreadsheet as expected (i.e. uk date format), but when writing the amendments back to the spreadsheet it converts them to US Date Format.

One Drive Link - [link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AoX6JVtrSyKjipE21aM6-9uFRdknqg?e=lVZxlU)

    TB_CompAdded.Value = Format(xComp.Range("B" & xLine).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    TB_CompAdded.Value = Format(xComp.Range("B" & xLine).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: Thanks for the help. I seemed to have solved the error. When pushing the data back to the spreadsheet I had for format "mm/dd/yyyy", not sure why but it resolved the problem.